# Is Base64 Encoded BSON smaller then BSON?

Tags: base64, bson

Is Base64 Encoded BSON smaller then BSON?

Comment: Measuring = Knowing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Piskvor's right, base64-encoded-anything is longer than raw. You base64-encode something to get it down a channel with a limited character repertoire, not as a means of reducing size.

Perhaps the question should be: Is Base64-encoded BSON smaller then **JSON**?

If so then JSON-vs-BSON is very much dependent on the content. For example arbitrary floating point numbers like `1.2345678901234567` are more efficiently stored in 8 binary bytes in BSON than the JSON string digit version. But the more common numbers like, say, `1`, are much more efficiently stored as strings in JSON.

For string values, BSON loses 4 bytes for a length word, but gets some back for every `"` and `\` JSON has to escape, plus more in strings with control characters where JSON has to use a hex sequence. (Some JSON encoders also `\u`-escape every non-ASCII character to ensure safe transmission regardless of character set.)

IMO: BSON does not have a big compactness advantage over JSON in general. Its strength lies more in simplicity of decoding in a low-level language, plus datatypes JavaScript doesn't have. It can have marginal advantages for binary strings and a few other cases; it's certainly worth checking for a particular workload. But it's telling that the examples in the BSON specification itself are considerably smaller in JSON.

As for base64-encoded BSON: the same, except 33% worse.

Comment: Your right Later on i was going to compare Base64 encoded BSON to JSON. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No: with base64, 3 bytes of plaintext become 4 bytes of encoded text, therefore the result will always be larger, no matter what the data payload is. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 1):

just wrote this as my soolution to shortify bson
please check, it can help you:

```
var bsonShortify = {
  encode:function(bson){
    return this._hex2urlBase(bson.substr(0,bson.length/2))+this._hex2urlBase(bson.substr(bson.length/2,bson.length/2));
  },
  decode:function(token){
    return this._urlBase2hex(token.substr(0,token.length/2))+this._urlBase2hex(token.substr(token.length/2,token.length/2));
  },
  _base:62,
  _baseChars:"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  _urlBase2hex:function(token){
    var s = 0, n, l = (n = token.split("")).length, i = 0;
    while(l--) s += this._baseChars.indexOf(n[i++]) * Math.pow(this._base, l);
    return s.toString(16);
  },
  _hex2urlBase:function(bson){
    var s = "", n = parseInt(bson,16);
    while(n) s = this._baseChars[n % this._base] + s, n = Math.floor(n / this._base);
    return s;
  } 
}
```

TEST

```
//we have bson
var bson = '4f907f7e53a58f4313000028';
//let's encode it
var urlstring = bsonShortify.encode(bson) // = OqAYQdCHijCDMbRg
//let's decode urlstring
var decoded_bson = bsonShortify.decode(urlstring); // = 4f907f7e53a58f4313000028

console.log('bson',bson);
console.log('urlstring',urlstring);
console.log('decoded_bson',decoded_bson);
```

Comment: I don't know that this answers the question of size comparison.  ('Not downvoting, just wondering)

Comment: can you please tell what is this text "4f907f7e53a58f4313000028",@Nedudi